# Convert a matrix in R into a upper triangular/lower triangular matrix with those corresponding entries

Tags: r, matrix

I have a symmetric matrix and I want to convert it into a upper triangular/lower triangular matrix in R. Is there a way of doing this ?

I am not able to do this using `upper.tri` and `lower.tri`. Using these gives me a matrix with entries as either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Check the example in `?upper.tri` or `?lower.tri`. Its pretty much similar to your question (and to the answer by @ujjwal below).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To get the upper triangular matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- 0
```

To remove diagonal, use:

`mat[lower.tri(mat,diag=TRUE)] <- 0` or `mat[!upper.tri(mat)] <- 0` as suggested in the comments by Karolis.

Answer (score 8):

While the previous answer is perfect, [the manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lower.tri.html) is your friend:

> ### Lower and Upper Triangular Part of a Matrix
>
> #### Description
>
> Returns a matrix of logicals the same size of a given matrix with
> entries TRUE in the lower or upper triangle.
>
> #### Usage
>
> ```
> lower.tri(x, diag = FALSE)
> upper.tri(x, diag = FALSE)
> ```
>
> #### Arguments
>
> ```
> x
> ```
>
> a matrix.
>
> ```
> diag
> ```
>
> logical. Should the diagonal be included?
>
> #### See Also
>
> [diag](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diag.html), [matrix](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html).
>
> #### Examples
>
> ```
> (m2 <- matrix(1:20, 4, 5))
> lower.tri(m2)
> m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- NA
> m2
> ```

Answer (score 5):

A simple way:

```
library(matrixcalc)

lower.triangle(X) #lower triangular

upper.triangle(X) #upper triangular
```

Or:

```
library(Matrix)

tril(X) #lower triangular

triu(X) #upper triangular
```

Comment: lower.triangle(X) #lower triangular (function not found!)

Comment: @JStrahl you need to install the matrixcalc package to use lower.triangle(X) and upper.triangle(X). install.packages("matrixcalc") and then library(matrixcalc)