# how to write genetic distance values between genotypes to csv file using POPPr package in R?

Tags: r, csv

I calculated genetic distance based on SNP genotype data for my genotypes using provesti distance using bitewise function. I used this following code for this

```
snpsdist<-bitwise.dist(snps)
save(snpsdist, ascii=TRUE, file="GPdist.CSV") 
write.table(snpsdist,"bitwise.csv")
```

I want my distance values like below format but I failed to do so

```
         A     B      C    
A       0
B       0.34   0
C       0.39   0.45   0
```

can any one help me to write my results as above format? any help in this regard would be highly appreciated, sorry if I am not following any coding standards in this post
Thanks and regard

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example or just enough information for us to decipher what your data looks like. Also, show what you've tried (but failed). Have you seen for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377199/convert-a-matrix-in-r-into-a-upper-triangular-lower-triangular-matrix-with-those)?

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions.

Convert the distance matrix into a full matrix. This will populate the upper triangle with a mirror image of the lower.

```
m <- as.matrix(dist(c(1, 3, 2, 5)))
m
#   1 2 3 4
# 1 0 2 1 4
# 2 2 0 1 2
# 3 1 1 0 3
# 4 4 2 3 0
```

You can replace the upper triangle with values of your choosing, like `NA`.

```
m[upper.tri(m)] <- NA
m
#   1  2  3  4
# 1 0 NA NA NA
# 2 2  0 NA NA
# 3 1  1  0 NA
# 4 4  2  3  0
```

Or you can replace the upper triangle with empty strings. This will force the matrix to be of character type.

```
m[upper.tri(m)] <- ""
m
#    1   2   3   4  
# 1 "0" ""  ""  "" 
# 2 "2" "0" ""  "" 
# 3 "1" "1" "0" "" 
# 4 "4" "2" "3" "0"

write.csv(m, "m.csv")
```

Whether any of these solutions will work depends on where you're planning to send the csv file (I'm assuming it is to be used by some other software).

Comment: Dear AkselaPlease find my file here https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive. first sheet contains the results what I got and 2nd sheet contains how I wish to have my results. Thanks in advance